# Displaying Android CTS results (xml/xsl) in Jenkins

Tags: xml, xslt, jenkins

I have a Jenkins job that executes android CTS tests, the results of which are located in a subdirectory, ie android-cts/repository/results/

The main file in this results directory is `testResult.xml` file, which contains all the test result data. It also references an `cts_result.xsl` and `cts_result.css` file for formatting, which are also in that directory.

In the HTML Publisher settings, the "HTML directory to archive" setting is set to that timestamped directory. The "Index Page[s]" setting is "testResult.xml"

When a job is complete, I see the link for the html report, but when I go there, the xml is not rendering with the .xsl and .css. It's just a big ugly wall of text.

Edit: I should that if I open the .xml file in a web browser, the file is displayed perfectly (cause it's using the .xsl and .css files).

Comment: After more investigation, it may be the sheer size of the results page I'm viewing.  Results from smaller CTS test runs (with a couple thousand tests) seem to load/render just fine. However, the results I'm trying to view have over 100k test case results.